# Angular Google Maps search bar won't operate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a search bar on my Angular Google Map. I've got the code below.(The code on the top is my JS, while the bottom is HTML. Couldn't find out how to label those. Sorry)

The search input field showed up just fine, it even did auto complete just fine. But then nothing really happens. It doesn't show the city or anything. So it really just is a useless text field. Most of this code I got from other sources. Though I did right some of it. Developer tools say it's all good, so I'm not sure where I went wrong. Help?

```js
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
  uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
  // key: 'your api key',
  v: '3.17',
  libraries: 'places'
  });
})




var events = {
    places_changed: function (searchBox) {
        var place = searchBox.getPlaces();
        if (!place || place == 'undefined' || place.length == 0) {
            console.log('no place data :(');
            return;
            }
        }
    }
    
    $scope.searchbox = {
                    template:'searchbox.tpl.html',
                    position: 'top',
                    events: events
                };
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="searchbox.tpl.html">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
                </script>


<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
        <ui-gmap-search-box
            template='searchbox.template'
            events='searchbox.events'
            position='searchbox.position'>
        </ui-gmap-search-box>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Comment: does `searchBox.getPlaces();` return a promise?

Comment: @DanielA.White That solved it. There was an typing error stopping it, made by my friend that I didn't notice. I'd give you best answer, but it was a comment. haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a search, it is likely async. So `.getPlaces` is returning a promise.